Ubuntu 24.04 upgradw failure
My Ubuntu 24.04 installation stopped at the upgrading phase about 20% through, froze the computer so I had to turn it off.
Upon restarting the computer cannot reboot and renders the computer disabled.
I would like to return to 22.o4.
What methods are necessary to attempt this?

CTL+ALT+F3 may give you a terminal to work from. If not then you can get the grub menu on boot by asserting ESC during boot. Then try to boot from recovery or a previous kernel. If that doesn't work then select the grub menu option and assert 'e' and remove 'quiet' from the boot script and start the boot. To start to fix this you need to find the first failure and work from there. Alternative: Backup data from a booted install media and do a fresh install

This question is similar to: How to fix broken 24.04.1 LTS upgrade which is missing necessary software?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
